# FATAL: no indexes found in config file '/mypath/config/development.sphinx.conf'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, thinking-sphinx

So, I'm using [Thinking Sphinx](https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx) and the heroku add-on [Flying Sphinx](http://info.flying-sphinx.com/) in production.

However, I seem to be getting the below error

```
using config file '/mypath/config/development.sphinx.conf'...
FATAL: no indexes found in config file '/mypath/config/development.sphinx.conf'
```

I've read a bunch of other S.O posts but none have helped solve my issue, more specifically, I'm using acts_as_taggable gem and the tags aren't being indexed but everything else is being indexed just fine.

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :clip, :with => :real_time do
  # fields
  indexes :name
  indexes sort_name, :sortable => true
  indexes description
  indexes taggings.tag.name, :as => :tags
end
```

I'm guessing it's because the taggings are an association and this is causing some issues.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addressed this via GitHub issues, but re-iterating here:

Method chains for fields/attributes in real-time indices must be exactly like what you'd call in your app yourself - so, `taggings.tag.name` is not valid. In reality, what you'd want is the following, within the context of a clip:

```
clip.taggings.collect(&:tag).collect(&:name)
```

However, that can't be applied within a Thinking Sphinx index, as it only allows for methods with *no* arguments. The work-around is to define a method in your model that returns a single string value of these tag names:

```
def tag_names
  taggings.collect(&:tag).collect(&:name).join(' ')
end
```

And then use that in your index definition:

```
indexes tag_names, :as => :tags
```

Now, you've changed your index definition, so you'll need to run the `rake ts:regenerate` rake task, because you're using real-time indices. Your question starts with indexing output, and the `ts:index` task only applies to SQL-backed indices, not real-time indices, so make sure you use `ts:regenerate` when changing index structures, and `ts:generate` if your Sphinx data isn't quite up-to-date (for example, if callbacks weren't fired when data was changed).